# preview for typescript (.ts) files are incorrectly assumed to be MPEG Transport Stream files

Tags: finder, preview

I have files with `.ts` extensions which are typescript, NOT MPEG-2 Transport Streams...

I changed the "Open With" for .ts files on my system to use TextEdit, but preview still thinks this is a quicktime playable file..  Is there a way to change this so that it will preview as a text file, and thus pressing space bar will display the text contents rather than just showing a quicktime icon?

[image]
[image]